# DryIoc resolve with a func

Tags: c#, dryioc

I'm trying to have objects being resolved as the result of `Func<>`.
But I don't find how to do it.

For instance, here I have a variable (function argument) `lazyInt` (which could be the result of long running computation of some sort) and which result is not required before a possible later usage.

```
        private Demo(Container c, Func<int> lazyInt) : base(c)
        {
            _container = c;
            c.Register<int>(made: Made.Of(/*???*/));
        }
```

I tried a bit using `ServiceInfo.Of`, etc. but with no success for the time being.
How can it be done?

Comment: May be you need a container.RegisterDelegate(_ => lazyInt());

Comment: I though there might be a preferred alternative as RegisterDelegate is not recommended whenever an alternative there is.

Comment: There is no way around if you already have pre-created delegate (lazyInt). Made.Of is better when you can write delegate as expression tree, so the tree can be parsed and analyzed.

Comment: I tried your code but then I can't resolve on int "Unable to resolve Int32."  for var result = demo.Resolve<int>();

Comment: Here is working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w6wn8U

Comment: Thanks, it work (I previously had omited the parenthesis container.RegisterDelegate(_ => lazyInt);).

Comment: Compiled these comments into a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `RegisterDelegate` instead of `Made.Of` to work with already created run-time delegate:

```
var c = new Container();

Func<int> lazyInt = () => 42;
c.RegisterDelegate(_ => lazyInt());

var shouldBe42 = c.Resolve<int>();
```

`Made.Of` is better when you can provide [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) with Method call or Property access for service creation. It enables DryIoc to parse the provided expression for diagnostics and put it directly into resulting factory delegate. As you already have a delegate object, then `Made.Of` won't do any good for you.